# Pandas fill empty values on one dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is something that I would be able to replicate easily in Excel with an XLOOKUP function, but I'm trying to do it with pandas.

I have 2 dataframes, say something like this:

df1

```
|first_name | last_name | dob      | value |
| Goku      | Saiyan    | 1/1/2021 |       |
| Vegetta   |  Super    | 8/7/1990 |       |
| Gohan     |  Son      | 4/20/1969|       |
```

df2

```
|first_name | last_name | dob      | value |
| Goku      | Saiyan    | 1/1/2021 |   50  |
| Vegetta   |  Super    | 8/7/1990 |   92  |
| Gohan     |  Son      | 4/20/1969|   31  |
| Trunks    |  Donald   | 7/1/1921 |   49  |
| New Name  |  Another  | 1/31/1992|   67  |
```

I would like to fill the `value` column in df1 from the `value` column in df2.

I cannot use `combine_first` because the dataframes have different index and different sizes.

If I use `pd.merge` then I get the `value_x` and `value_y` where `value_y` has the data that I want, but I need to do more process to have it where I want on `df1['value']`

I basically want to match the first name, last name and dob on both dataframes and receive the `value` from df2.

It's probably a simple issue, but I have been struggling with the different methods that I've tried and I think there must be something that I'm missing because it shouldn't be that complicated.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think your pd.merge approach is the best bet. You can simply drop the columns from df2 that you don't need, do your merge (setting copy=False), and then use pd.where to fill the missing values. You'll have to drop the extra 'value' column at the end, but that's only one column which isn't terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `value` column from `df1` does not contain existing value, you can drop it and use `merge`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1.drop(columns='value'), df2, how='left',
             on=['first_name', 'last_name', 'dob'])

  first_name last_name        dob  value
0       Goku    Saiyan   1/1/2021     50
1    Vegetta     Super   8/7/1990     92
2      Gohan       Son  4/20/1969     31
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map.

Create a dict of firts_name; value from df2 and map to df1's first_name.

```
df1 =df1.assign(value=df1['first_name'].map(dict(zip(df2['first_name'],df2['value']))))



   first_name last_name        dob  value
0       Goku    Saiyan   1/1/2021     50
1    Vegetta     Super   8/7/1990     92
2      Gohan       Son  4/20/1969     31
```